# How to create a door which opens automatically for players but not for mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I would like to make a door that is easy to open by players, but  not mobs.
Tried using a button to power the door but clicks are inaccurate while playing on laptop, rendering the door an obstacle, and also jump to activate a tripwire to power the door, but it just closes too quickly, rendering the door an obstacle again.
An extra point is that no wooden doors as I am playing on hard difficulty and I am playing on survival so no commands, just redstone.
So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way I know of to make a player only door is to abuse stairs and fences. Since a fence (F) is ~0.5 blocks wide, and stairs (S) are missing 1/4 of a block you can stand between the fence and the stair. And so using four stairs and three fences you can make a player only door. Finally it needs to be surrounded in blocks (B), so that mobs can't get around the setup. such as walking through the middle.

If looking face-on you should have:

```
BBBBB
BSFSB
B F B
BSFSB
```

The top left stair has to have a gap in the bottom right corner, the top right in the bottom left corner etc.

Which visually looks like:

[image: Image of mob-only door]

Comment: Will skeletons try to shoot through the door?

Comment: @lkp111138 Yes, skeletons will shoot as it they use line-of sight with real blocks models. Pathfinding only sees blocks as solid or non-solid, fences for example are 2 pathfinder blocks high

Comment: This works for some mobs but anything that can go through one block high gaps like spiders or baby zombies will get through!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get really crazy, you can use a **player-differentiating clock**, like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfXWiqCNMEI). A tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOEHrF2cuzg).

It obviously has the disadvantages of costing quite a bit of resources, creating a lot of piston noise and a bit of lag and it could be considered bug-using, but otherwise it's perfect: You can just walk straight through the door, but mobs can't get in, not even skeleton arrows, thrown items etc.

Answer (score -3):

firstly, you can of course use fences or a lily pad parkour but you can also use a hoe-activation door.

how to make this, just search up 'How to Make a Hoe-Activated Door in Minecraft' on youtube.

how it works is a grass block is a non-transparent block
once tilled it is transparent and redstone doesn't travel through

or you could use a card-reader system

again, search how to make that on youtube

hope that brought you on some ideas

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful, it more or less suggesting things to research, in which is very indirect.

Comment: Please try to answer the question without relying on outside sources. Try to explain how to create a hoe-activated door and a card-reader system in your own words. A link to a youtube video can help, but shouldn't be the only content.